# Conditional probability: compute $P(B)$ when $P(B|A), P(A'|B)$ and $P(A)$ are given

Tags: probability

The question goes like this:

Two events $A$ and $B$ are such that $P(A) = 3/4, P(B|A) = 1/5$ and $P(A'|B) = 4/7$.

I've worked out (correctly) that $P(A \text{ and } B) = 3/20$ (this was a prior part of the question), but I'm not sure how to work out $P(B)$.

I have calculated that $P(B|A') = 1 - P(B'|A') = 1 - 4/7 = 3/7$ and then did $P(B|A) \times P(B|A') = 3/35$, but this is not correct (the answer should be $9/35$).

Where have I gone wrong? I'm assuming I'm missing something at the last step.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\Pr(B)=\Pr(B\cap A)+\Pr(B\cap A').$$
You have computed $\Pr(B\cap A)$.  The other term, $\Pr(B\cap A')$, can be found in a similar way.

Comment: Ah I see; they are both mutually exclusive events so we can add them up. However, why wouldn't P(B|A') + P(B|A) work?; they are both mutually exclusive events, so we should be able to add them up.

Comment: The formula you are proposing is not right. Toss a fair coin and a die. Let $A$ be the event Head, and $B$ be the event we toss a $6$ on the die. Then $\Pr(B\mid A)=\Pr(B\mid A')=1/6$. Their sum is $1/3$, which is nor $\Pr(B)$.

Comment: However, the examples you have given are independent of each other; why wouldn't this work for two dependent events (like in the original question: A and B must be non-independent events for P(B|A) + P(B'|A) $\ne$ 1.

Comment: There are various degrees of non-independence. The formula would fail most of the time.

Comment: At the level of the question asked, just keep in mind two things: (i) You _cannot_ add or subtract conditional probabilities unless the conditions are the _same._ $$P(A\cup B\mid C) = P(A\mid C)+P(B\mid C)-P(A\cap B\mid C)$$ is correct; $$P(B)=P(B\mid A)+P(B\mid A^c)\tag{1}$$ is not.  (ii) $B\mid A$ and $B\mid A^c$ are not _events_, and you cannot claim that they are mutually exclusive because $A$ and $A^c$ are mutually exclusive. On the other hand, $B\cap A$ and $B\cap A^c$ are indeed events, and it is true that $$P(B)=P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap A ^c)=P(B\mid A)P(A)+P(B\mid A^c)P(A^c).\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint you have been given above,

$P(A' \cap B) =P(A'|B)P(B) $ so $$ P(B)(1-P(A'|B))=P(A\cap B)\\
  P(B)=P(A\cap B)/(1-P(A'|B))$$